# Socket creation fails after many successful attempts

Tags: python, perl, sockets

I'm using a client/server connection on "localhost", with the Server written in Python and the client written in Perl.

Each time the (Perl) client transmits data to the server, I currently create a new socket with the line:

```
my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET ( PeerHost => inet_ntoa($self->{server}),
                                    PeerPort => $self->{port},  Proto => 'tcp' );
```

I then send data with the send method and call shutdown with option 1 (done writing). Then I receive a response with the recv method and call shutdown with option 2 (done reading). Then I call close on the socket. In Perl this reads:

```
$socket->send($record);
shutdown($socket, 1);
my $response = "";
$socket->recv($response, BUF_SIZE);
shutdown($socket, 0);
$socket->close();
```

As my socket is stored in a local variable, I would expect it to get garbage collected, once I leave my send function. However, the memory footprint gets larger by some kilobytes, each time I create a new socket.

Then, after many thousands of calls, the creation of a new socket fails. If I then wait for some seconds and try again, it usually gets created OK, although the memory footprint of the process didn't change during that time.

Can someone tell me a reason for this strange behavior or even a solution to avoid it?

Just for completion - this is how the server socket is created in Python:

```
comm_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
comm_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
comm_socket.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
comm_socket.listen(1)
```

Comment: Are you testing that your close/shutdown etc. is in fact working, and what does 'netstat -a' tell you when it's misbehaving? Because this sounds like a too many open sockets problem.

Comment: You tell us. Check the return values and `$!` for each of your socket function calls.

Comment: I agree with Sobrique; I don't know if what you're doing allows for it but if it's possible I suggest refactoring your implementation to reuse sockets if possible

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly! Neither of the function calls on the socket ever flags an error. Only when creation of a new socket fails, I get

    "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted."

This problem occurs frequently for a few seconds; then all continues to work fine for some minutes until the problem returns (again only for a few seconds). When the problem occurs, I wait 1..3 seconds and retry creating the socket until I finally succeed.

Comment: David: What do you mean with "why do you do this?". Do you mean re-creating the socket all the time? If so: I don't know, how to re-use it. Can you tell me?

Comment: Sobrique: I'm sorry, but I'm on a Windows machine and the problem disappears after some seconds. I'm not sure, whether I could issue a meaningful "netstat -a" at the right point in time. Anyway, the error message implies that there's something going on, which makes the kernel assume, that the socket is still in use. If I knew, how to re-use the socket, I think the problem would be solved.

Comment: Do you want to handle only "one the same host" situation? YES => consider switching to UDP (instead of TCP) over UNIX socket.

Comment: Hi Andrzej, thanks for the hint. At the moment, I don't know at all, what the implications are, if I change from TCP to UDP. I even don't know, if I have to change the way, the data transmission is done (currently I do ->send() and ->recv() calls and I ->shutdown() and then ->close() the connection to tell the server, that I'm done. Without these, it simply waits for more data and I couldn't get it working).

Answer (score 0):

I know now, what happens: The hint from Sobrique was the essential one. I checked with "netstat -a" how the situation looks like, before I run my program and again, when it is running.

It appears that each socket I create stays there for some minutes, even if it has been closed by Perl. The connection stays in the list in state TIME_WAIT. If I create and destroy the socket many thousand times in a period shorter than the waiting time, then the system runs out of ephemeral ports (which are the port number automatically assigned to the client socket when it is created; this counts up from 0xC000 = 49152 to 0xFFFF = 65535 or so). When 65535 is reached before 49152 has been cleaned up, no new socket can be created. After some time, the system cleans up some connections, thus freeing some ephemerall port numbers, and then new sockets can be created again.

Now I found several posts that tell how to make the waiting time shorter, which would make the kernel clean up the list much quicker and my application wouldn't be fast enough anymore to overrun the system.

However I didn't find the registry key on my system. Maybe I have to get into Admin mode - but that's another problem that should be easier to solve...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi - I still couldn't make it work. Changing the timeout is anyway not the best solution. Although I have the SO_REUSEADDR flag set, the connections are not re-used. I also tried on the client side (which might tell you, that I really don't know, what exactly is going on when the connection is established between client and server). I've been reading through so many tutorials now, but they all only handle these one-shot clients. I never found any example, that showed how to implement a client, that is constantly re-connecting.